# Eclipse - Unexpected exception when trying to install m2e connectors

Tags: windows-10, java, eclipse, maven

When I try to install m2e connectors in Eclipse (Window > Preferences > Maven > Discovery > Open Catalog), I'm given this message:

```
Unexpected exception: org/eclipse/equinox/internal/p2/core/helpers/SecureXMLUtil
```

Here's details in Error Log:

```
eclipse.buildId=4.7.0.I20170612-0950
java.version=1.8.0_231
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.rcp.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.rcp.product

org.eclipse.equinox.p2.ui.discovery
Error
Tue Nov 05 11:02:21 CST 2019
Unexpected exception: org/eclipse/equinox/internal/p2/core/helpers/SecureXMLUtil

java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext.run(ModalContext.java:398)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.run(WizardDialog.java:980)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.internal.discovery.wizards.MavenCatalogViewer.updateCatalog(MavenCatalogViewer.java:156)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.ui.discovery.wizards.CatalogPage$2.run(CatalogPage.java:78)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:37)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:182)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:4213)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3820)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:818)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:794)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.internal.discovery.MavenDiscovery.launchWizard(MavenDiscovery.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.internal.discovery.MavenDiscovery.launchWizard(MavenDiscovery.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.internal.discovery.preferences.DiscoveryPreferencePage$1.widgetSelected(DiscoveryPreferencePage.java:62)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:249)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4428)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1079)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4238)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3817)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:818)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:794)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.dialogs.WorkbenchPreferenceDialog.open(WorkbenchPreferenceDialog.java:211)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.OpenPreferencesAction.run(OpenPreferencesAction.java:63)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.Action.runWithEvent(Action.java:473)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:565)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.lambda$4(ActionContributionItem.java:397)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4428)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1079)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4238)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3817)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$5.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1155)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:336)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1044)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:153)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.lambda$3(Workbench.java:680)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:336)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:594)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:151)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:388)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:243)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:653)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:590)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1499)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/equinox/internal/p2/core/helpers/SecureXMLUtil
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.discovery.compatibility.DirectoryParser.parse(DirectoryParser.java:41)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.discovery.compatibility.RemoteBundleDiscoveryStrategy$1.process(RemoteBundleDiscoveryStrategy.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.discovery.compatibility.util.TransportUtil.readResource(TransportUtil.java:109)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.discovery.compatibility.RemoteBundleDiscoveryStrategy.performDiscovery(RemoteBundleDiscoveryStrategy.java:81)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.discovery.Catalog.performDiscovery(Catalog.java:85)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.internal.discovery.wizards.MavenCatalogViewer$2.run(MavenCatalogViewer.java:164)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:119)
```

I find similar error in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10562012/eclipse-marketplace-error-unexpected-exception-org-eclipse-equinox-internal-p) when surfing the Marketplace, but my Marketplace seems work and it seems not help when I tried to adjust my network configuration.

What might be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I'm not sure what really happened. But I seem to fix the problem by updating Eclipse the newest version (19-09) from Oxygen. I guess there's something wrong with version compatibility.